# Plotting binned data using sum instead of count

Tags: r, histogram, bar-chart, data-visualization

I've tried to search for an answer, but can't seem to find the right one that does the job for me.

I have a dataset (`data`) with two variables: people's ages (`age`) and number of awards (`awards`)

My objective is to plot the number of awards against age in R. FYI, a person can have multiple awards and people can have the same age.

I tried to plot a histogram and barplot, but the problem with that is that it counts the number of observations instead of summing the number of awards.

A sample dataset:

```
age <- c(21,22,22,25,30,34,45,26,37,46,49,21)
awards <- c(0,3,2,1,0,0,1,3,1,1,1,1)
data <- data.frame(cbind(age,awards))
```

What I'm looking for is a histogram (or barplot) that represents this data.

Ideally, I'd want the ages to be split into age groups. For example,
20-30, 31-40, 41-50 and then the total number of awards for each group.

The age group would be on the x-axis and the total number of awards for each age group would be on the y-axis.

Thanks!

Comment: How does a 'person' come into play here?

Comment: Also share `dput(data)` rather than an image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use the `aggregate` function and then use the `ggplot2` package. I don't make too many barplots in base `R` these days so I'm not sure of the best way to do it without loading `ggplot2`:

#### create sample data

```
#data
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(age = sample(20:50, 200, replace = TRUE),
                  awards = rpois(200, 3))
head(dat)
  age awards
1  28      2
2  44      6
3  32      3
4  47      3
5  49      2
6  21      5
```

#### By age

```
#aggregate

sum_by_age <- aggregate(awards ~ age, data = dat, FUN = sum)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sum_by_age, aes(x = age, y = awards))+
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image: age plot]

#### By age group

```
#create groups

dat$age_group <- ifelse(dat$age <= 30, '20-30',
                        ifelse(dat$age <= 40, '30-40',
                               '41 +'))

sum_by_age_group <- aggregate(awards ~ age_group, data = dat, FUN = sum)

ggplot(sum_by_age_group, aes(x = age_group, y = awards))+
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image: age group plot]

#### Note

We could skip the `aggregate` step altogether and just use:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = age, y = awards)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image: age plot no aggregate]

but I don't prefer that way because I think having an intermediate data step may be useful within your analytical pipeline for comparisons other than visualizing.

Comment: Nice answer, but you may want to change your bottom group to `<= 30` since the code will put anything less than 30 in the bottom bracket.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, I am adding the base `R` solution to @bouncyball's great answer.  I will use their synthetic data, but I will use `cut` to create the age groups before aggregation.

```
# Creates data for plotting
> set.seed(123)
> dat <- data.frame(age = sample(20:50, 200, replace = TRUE),
                    awards = rpois(200, 3))

# Created a new column containing the age groups
> dat[["ageGroups"]] <- cut(dat[["age"]], c(-Inf, 20, 30, 40, Inf),
                            right = FALSE)
```

`cut` will divide up a set of numeric data based on breaks defined in the second argument.  `right = FALSE` flips the breaks so values the groups would include the lower values rather than the upper ones (ie `20 <= x < 30` rather than the default of `20 < x <= 30`).  The groups do not have to be equally spaced.  If you do not want to include data above or below a certain value, simply remove the `Inf` from the end or `-Inf` from the beginning respectively, and the function will return `<NA>` instead.  If you would like to give your groups names, you can do so with the `labels` argument.

Now we can `aggregate` based on the groups we created.

```
> (summedGroups <- aggregate(awards ~ ageGroups, dat, FUN = sum))
  ageGroups awards
1   [20,30)    188
2   [30,40)    212
3 [40, Inf)    194
```

Finally, we can plot these data using the `barplot` function.  The key here is to use `names` for the age groups.

```
> barplot(summedGroups[["awards"]], names = summedGroups[["ageGroups"]])
```

[image: summed barplot]

Comment: @bouncyball thanks, I made an edit and decided to use the `right = TRUE` argument instead since that seems to match closer to what the user wanted, and I mentioned the `labels` argument is an option.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for showing a base `R` implementation